# BULK COLLECT INTO and just INTO inside one sql block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got a SQL block inside my PL/SQL stored procedure. This block uses bulk collect to collect values into a user-defined type.

```
TYPE risks IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
o_risks risks;

... 

SELECT DISTINCT risk
BULK   COLLECT
INTO   o_risks
FROM   schema.risks
WHERE parent_id = any_id
```

But I also want to save `max(other_column_name)` from this SQL block into number variable. Is it possible when BULK COLLECT is used? Of course, I could just create another block, but it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`CAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CAST.htm) and [`COLLECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions024.htm#SQLRF06304):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE risks IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE TABLE risk_table ( risk, other_column_name, parent_id ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
DECLARE
  o_risks             risks;
  o_other_column_name RISK_TABLE.OTHER_COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
  any_id              RISK_TABLE.PARENT_ID%TYPE := 1;
BEGIN
  SELECT CAST( COLLECT( DISTINCT risk ) AS risks ),
         MAX( other_column_name )
  INTO   o_risks, o_other_column_name
  FROM   risk_table
  WHERE  parent_id = any_id;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Max other column name: ' || o_other_column_name );
  FOR i IN 1 .. o_risks.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Risk ' || i || ': ' || o_risks(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
Max other column name: 4
Risk 1: 1
Risk 2: 2
Risk 3: 3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53e7c94c68390ec313963268abf2fa38)*

If you are on a version where `COLLECT( DISTINCT ... )` does not work then you can use `SET( CAST( COLLECT( risk ) AS risks ) )` to get distinct values.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why my Oracle says that in line `SELECT CAST( COLLECT( DISTINCT risk ) AS risks )` there is an error ORA-00902: invalid datatype while in db<>fiddle everything works great.

Comment: Seems like it is because my type is just declared inside the procedure while yours is created

Comment: @РусланХ Yes, you cannot use a type declared in a PL/SQL scope in the SQL scope (at least in Oracle 11g and earlier). However, you can use types declared in the SQL scope in both SQL and PL/SQL scopes so you will need to declare it in SQL and not PL/SQL.

Comment: I'm going to use your solution. The answer was very useful and informative. Thank you!